# How to separate Awesome's `rc.lua` configuration into multiple files?

Tags: files, configuration, window-manager, awesome, lua

I've just moved to Awesome WM from OpenBox. I like that it's very extensible, customizable and I have huge control about window layout. I like structured and organized things and I'd like to separate that huge `.config/awesome/rc.lua` configuration into multiple files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply place code in a separate file and include it with

```
dofile("somefile.lua")
```

Note: The working directory is `$HOME`. To specify a file relative to `rc.lua` you can use

```
dofile(awful.util.getdir("config") .. "/" .. "somefile.lua")
```

If it's more than just *some code* and it might be used
by others as well, it might make sense to create a lua module which
can be included with

```
somemodule = require("somemodule")
```

Comment: It works at 50%, I have to specify full path instead of relative path

Comment: @Miro fixed, see update.

Comment: On Ubuntu, Awesome's require function looks automatically in .config/awesome/, so you can make a require of any file you put there.

Answer (score 5):

To move code into a different file, you create a module and require the module in the rc.lua.

To create a module, you simply call `module (name [, ···])` in the script that has the code you pulled out of the original script. [Lua reference - module](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-module).

To use the module you created, you just call `require (modname)`. [Lua reference - require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require).

There is an [excellent tutorial on the Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) that explains this with examples. And if you want to see how `module()` really works, there is an [article on Play With Lua](http://www.playwithlua.com/?p=39) that starts by writing an implementation of module().

Comment: Note that starting with awesome-3.5 the lua version was updated to 5.2, where the `module()` function is deprecated. Therefore the module must be assigned to a variable, like `modname = require ("modname")`